# How does this algorithm generate all subsets of a set

Tags: c

I am currently taking a course in query optimization and I have an algorithm that calculates the costs of joining all subsets of a given set of relations. To do that, we are given a subroutine enumerating all these subsets. In our script, it says: "[...] code fragment with which subset bitvector representations can be generated very efficiently. In C, this fragment looks as follows:

```
S1 = S & - S;
do { /* do something with subset S1 */
S1 = S & (S1 - S);
} while (S1 != S);
```

S represents the input set. S1 iterates through all subsets of S where S itself and the empty set are not considered.

However, I do not understand it: When we take the set difference of S and S, we get the empty set. So the while loop will always output the empty set as S1 and never terminate. What am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: *"When we take the set difference of S and S, we get ..."* I think there's a typo.

Comment: I wouldve done that if I had one

Comment: Have you worked it out by hand on paper using binary notation? Always my first step when I see some bit fiddling I don't already understand.

Comment: @nick_dataFE The first step in understanding code like this is to create your own [mcve], so that you can compile and run the code. Then you can either add printfs, or use a debugger, to see what's happening in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When we take the set difference of S and S, we get the empty set. So the while loop will always output the empty set as S1 and never terminate. What am I missing?

`S` and `S1` are integers used as bitvectors, meaning that each bit corresponds to one of the possible set elements, with the presence or absence of that element in the subset corresponding to whether its bit takes the value 1 or 0.  The difference operator `-` is not a *set* difference, it is an *arithmetic* difference.

The code assumes two's complement representation for signed integers.  In this convention, the representation of the arithmetic inverse of any operand can be formed by flipping all the bits of its representation and adding 1 to the result (treating it as an unsigned operand and ignoring overflow).  From this emerges the property that **`S & - S` evaluates to an integer in which all bits are zero except the least-significant bit (if any) that is set in `S`**.

Example: Suppose `S` is a 32-bit integer with value 22.  The binary representation of `S` is

```
00000000000000000000000000010110
```

Flipping all the bits produces

```
11111111111111111111111111101001
```

Adding 1 produces

```
11111111111111111111111111101010
```

, which is the representation of -22.  Computing the bitwise `&` with `S` turns off all bits that are not set in `S`, yielding

```
00000000000000000000000000000010
```

.  As advertised, this has all bits zero except the bit at the position of the least-significant 1 bit in S.

The `S1 = S & (S1 - S)` would perhaps be more easily understood if reformulated as `S1 = S & (S1 + (-S))`, or even better as `S1 = S & (S1 + (~S) + 1)`.  Given that all the bits that are set in `S1` are also set in `S`, adding `~S` just turns on all the bits that are not set in `S`, too.  Furthermore adding 1 to that will flip all the least-significant bits up to and including the first that is not set in `S1 + (~S)`, which is necessarily one that *is* set in `S` (because we just turned on all the ones that weren't). Then the bitwise `&` turns back off all the bits that are not set in `S`.  **The overall result is as if we count upward by one, using a counter composed of only those bits that are set in `S`.**

Example: continuing from the above, `S1 + ~S` is

```
00000000000000000000000000000010 + 11111111111111111111111111101001
==
11111111111111111111111111101011
```

Adding 1 yields

```
11111111111111111111111111101100
```

And masking off the bits not set in S yields

```
00000000000000000000000000000100
```

You can verify for yourself that the next iterations produce, in succession

```
00000000000000000000000000000110
00000000000000000000000000010000
00000000000000000000000000010010
00000000000000000000000000010100
00000000000000000000000000010110
```

, where the last of those is equal to `S`.

It may also be interesting to note that the original `S1 = S & -S` is just a special case of this, as if `S1` were initially 0: `S1 = S & (0 - S)`.

---

Note well that the formulation you asked about serves the general case, where the initial `S` is an arbitrary subset of all the possible elements.  If we could assume that `S` would be a bitvector representing all possible elements, using its rightmost bits, then we could use this alternative, which is much easier to follow:

```
for (int S1 = 1; S1 < S; S1++) {
    /* do something with subset S1 */
}
```

---

Note also that **there is a flaw in the original code presented**.  It is supposed to avoid considering the full set `S` or the empty set, but it will consider both before it stops if `S` represents a set containing exactly one element.  To avoid that, it needs to test the termination condition before the first iteration, maybe just by using a `while` loop instead of a `do .. while`:

```
S1 = S & - S;
while (S1 != S) {
    /* do something with subset S1 */
    S1 = S & (S1 - S);
}
```

Comment: Thanky you So much! This was really helpful!